# passport js deserialize user, variable undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to build a backend for a web app, but I'm stuck on passport. Right now I can register a user and log that user in, but I can not log in twice in a row. Whenever deserialize user is called I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined" I see that user is undefined but it is defined when I call it on login() and signup()

```
var login = require('./login');
var signup = require('./signup');

module.exports = function (passport: any, user: any) {

// Passport needs to be able to serialize and deserialize users to support persistent login sessions
passport.serializeUser(function (user: any, done: any) {
    done(undefined, user.username);
});

// deserialize user 
passport.deserializeUser(function (id: any, done: any) {

    user.findOne(id).then(function (user: any) {

        if (user) {
            done(null, user.get());
        } else {
            done("error", undefined);
        }
    });
});

// Setting up Passport Strategies for Login and SignUp/Registration
login(passport, user);
signup(passport, user);

}
```

in my app.ts file i implement the strategies like this:

```
var models = require("./config/models/User");
require('./config/passport/init')(passport, models.user);
```

signup.js

```
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = function(passport : any, user : any) {

var User = user

passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy(
{
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback

}, function(req: Request, username: string, password: string, done: any) {

    var User = user

    console.log("signup"+User)

    var generateHash = function(password: string) {
        return bCrypt.hashSync(password, bCrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);        
    };

    User.findOne({
        where: {
            username: username
        }
    }).then(function(user: any) {

        if (user)     
        {
            console.log('already taken')
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'That email is already taken'
            });
        } else {

            var userPassword = generateHash(password);
            var data =
                {
                    username: username,
                    password: userPassword,
                    firstname: req.body.firstname,
                    lastname: req.body.lastname
                };

                User.create(data).then(function(newUser: any, created: boolean) {

                if (!newUser) {      
                    return done(null, false);
                }

                if (newUser) {
                    return done(null, newUser);
                }
            });    
        }     
    });
}

));

}
```

login.js

```
import { passport } from '../../app'
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');


module.exports = function(passport : any, user : any) {

//LOCAL SIGNIN
passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy(

{

    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email

    usernameField: 'username',

    passwordField: 'password',

    passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback

},


function(req : Request, username : string, password : string, done : any) {

    var User = user;

    console.log("login: "+User)

    var isValidPassword = function(userpass : string, password : string) {

        return bCrypt.compareSync(password, userpass);

    }

    User.findOne({
        where: {
            username: username
        }
    }).then(function(user : any) {

        if (!user) {

            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'User does not exist'
            });

        }

        if (!isValidPassword(user.password, password)) {

            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Incorrect password.'
            });

        }


        var userinfo = user.get();
        return done(null, userinfo);


    }).catch(function(err : Error) {

        console.log("Error:", err);

        return done(null, false, {
            message: 'Something went wrong with your Signin'
        });

    });


}

));

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of `login` and `signup` as well?

Comment: you are serializing a user using `username` and trying to deserialize using `id`. should either be `id` or `username` in both functions

Comment: login and signup added,

Comment: how will it get username passed? I thought that it saved username under id in the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself,

I imported the model like so:

```
var models = require("../models/User");
```

then I changed the findOne call like so:

```
models.user.findOne({ where: {username: id} }).then(function (user: any) {

        if (user) {
            done(null, user.get());
        } else {
            done("error", undefined);
        }
    });
```